# How can I run Gitk on WSL 2?

Tags: wsl-2, gitk

How can I run Gitk on WSL 2?

I already installed Gitk in WSL 2.

After I installed Gitk, I tried to run it but it failed with below error log:

```
application-specific initialization failed: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
Error in startup script: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
    while executing
"load /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtk8.6.so Tk"
    ("package ifneeded Tk 8.6.8" script)
    invoked from within
"package require Tk"
    (file "/usr/bin/gitk" line 10)
```

Could you help me how can run Gitk on WSL 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can install and run gitk straight from ubuntu terminal on Windows 11, using `apt install`.

I've just followed the steps from the following post and it worked:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/tutorials/gui-apps

I had to update not only the graphic driver but also the WSL.

Now, I can use either gitk or any linux app on Windows 11.

Comment: Good. thanks for your comment. According to link you mentioned it seems needs windows 11. After update to windows 11, I try and let you know. thanks

Comment: This answer is a good addition. :) But it would be even better it you included the gist of the solution in the answer text! Quite often I run across old answer with links to external pages that no longer exist.

Comment: Windows 11 / wsl2. it seems working fine. good.

Answer (score 1):

If git is installed on windows, you can find the gitk.exe by typing the following command to windows cmd:

```
where gitk
```

you can reach this folder from your wsl by changing the path e.g. from

```
C:\Git\cmd\gitk.exe
```

to

```
/mnt/c/Git/cmd/gitk.exe
```

and by typing this path to the terminal of your linux distribution, gitk can be opened.

UPDATE:

If you want to open gitk by typing it, you can add the path to ~/.bashrc with the following command (needed only once):

```
echo 'alias gitk="/mnt/c/Git/cmd/gitk.exe"' >> ~/.bashrc
```

And after that you can open gitk like:

```
gitk
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. gitk which I tried is installed in wsl, and it seems couldn't work because if gui limitation on wsl. And I tried with gitk which installed in windows and it works properly

Comment: @acabor Isn't this just gitk for windows?

Comment: @leeand00 gitk is installed on windows, but you can use it for you repos in wsl without limitation, and you have the gui this way.

Comment: @acgabor I didn't think it would like the paths.